# Need Help to understand math on how to draw liner trendline in php

Tags: php, mysql, math, charts, calculator

I was going through the first answer on [How do I calculate a trendline for a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224/how-do-i-calculate-a-trendline-for-a-graph). The answer says

> Given that the trendline is straight, find the slope by choosing any
>   two points and calculating:
>
> (A) slope = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
>
> Then you need to find the offset for the line. The line is specified
>   by the equation:
>
> (B) y = offset + slope*x
>
> So you need to solve for offset. Pick any point on the line, and solve
>   for offset:
>
> (C) offset = y/(slope*x)

I'm pathetic in Math. So I need some help to understand the equation in programming term. Lets say I have stock data containing Date, Open, High Low, Close and Volume. If I am not wrong I have to calculate X Axis first as per this answer [Calculate a trendline when the x-axis uses dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008003/calculate-a-trendline-when-the-x-axis-uses-dates?noredirect=1&lq=1) I could use mysql query to calculate X1-X2( which I am assuming difference between First and Last Date). And for Y axis Last Low Price - First Low Price (Still Assuming).
But in next stage I'm stuck. How would I calculate x or offset and on third y? Can someone please help me to understand it?

Comment: I also found a math equation [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/what-is-the-equation-used-to-calculate-a-linear-trendline) however as I explained I'm no good in math.

Comment: Smells like `teen homework`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Lol no. I work in Customer Service industry. When I get time I try to learn some programming. That's kind of addiction to me.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I studied commerce that's why :/

Comment: Do you want a line that fits only the first and the last data point or do you want to fit a line to all of the data points?

Comment: @evan058 I just need a straight line which fits first and last point.