# Can I add a Trendline to an RDLC report?

Tags: charts, rdlc

I have an RDLC report based on custom Data sets used in a WPF application.
I have a Chart with a simple line chart. 
IS there a way I can add a trendline to this RDLC report?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently, and just solved it this very minute.

My solution (might not be the best) was to use a stored procedure from the same database as the data to add 'trend' data to the columns returned.

To do the same, you'd need some knowledge of linear regressions, etc. Which I got from stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224/how-do-i-calculate-a-trendline-for-a-graph)

Are you using a database driven dataset or a static dataset, such as XML?
If you're using SQL Server, I can paste the function I used and you can take from it what you like =)

Comment: I am using statis Datasets that are filled from some user input, not using SQL so I guess the stored procedure idea is not an option for me

Comment: If the dataset isn't too large you might find calculating the trendline programmatically could be your best option?