# How to find the equation of a curve given the data set (x,y) in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, find, regression, equations

I am new to VB.NET and I am trying to write code in vb.net to find a equation when data points are given. For example (1,5),(2,6) etc.

I need to find a equation(not necessarily always linear) from the given points.

I tried to use the help given in

[How do I calculate a trendline for a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224/how-do-i-calculate-a-trendline-for-a-graph)

but couldn't figure out how to get equation.

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on your needs. Do you want an interpolation or a curve approximation?

Comment: What do you mean by "not necessarily always linear"? With two data points it doesn't make much sense to try to estimate anything more complicated (there will be an infinite number of solutions). What sort of data are you trying to estimate?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)

Basically it's a field in numerical analysis, and it helps you create a [polynomial representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) of the data points.