# Drawing trend-line on the line diagram in c3js

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, c3.js, trendline

I need to draw trend-line on simple line graph in c3js but i can't seem to find a built-in way to do that? If that's not possible, how do i calculate trend-line (linear regression) data to display on the chart?

Thanks

Comment: What is 'trend-line'? How does it supposed to look like? What data do you have? You should explain what you want more precisely for us to help

Comment: I know of that term from Excel, but i think it's proper name is Linear Regression. I'll update my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in solution (yet), but I'll put in my two cents in case someone can create something for c3.js specifically.

You may have to calculate the start/end points using one of these methods:

- [How do I calculate a trendline for a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224/how-do-i-calculate-a-trendline-for-a-graph)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204020/what-is-the-equation-used-to-calculate-a-linear-trendline/204021#204021

There are also D3.js solutions here:

- http://bl.ocks.org/benvandyke/8459843
- http://www.localwisdom.com/blog/2014/01/get-trend-line-javascript-graph-linear-regression/